# REACT NATIVE [ TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.type.displayName')]

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I was trying to create a login page using react native and native-base. I did follow the instructions from the docs but I still got an error in my coding, Would you guys help me to find where I made wrong at? Thx

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import {
  Container,
  Content,
  Form,
  Item,
  Input,
  Label,
  Button,
  Text
} from "native-base";

class Customerlogin extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <View>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="#EE5FD6" barStyle="light-content" />
        </View>
        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Item floatingLabel>
              <Label> Username </Label> <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item floatingLabel last>
              <Label> Password </Label> <Input />
            </Item>
          </Form>

          <Button rounded warning>
            <Text> Sign In </Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Customerlogin;
```

Thx b4.

Comment: Code looks correct, is there any other screen where you're using `native-base` ?

Comment: Works fine on my PC...

Comment: @PritishVaidya no, only this page yet. I don't know why it crashed if I using those floatinglabel

Comment: @Yossi. Wow.. Is there a chance that the reason of this error is because of the version?

Comment: I cannot say without knowing the environment you have. How did you create the app? How does your app.json look?